# Which is correct: "it's not a big deal to me" or "it's not a big deal for me"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, to-for

What is the correct way to say it?

> - It's not a big deal to me.
> - It's not a big deal for me.

Also, should I use "it's *not*" or "it's *no*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either is acceptable.  I would probably choose "for me", personally, but I would not think it strange to hear someone speak either form.

As for your second question, I would say that "It's no big deal for me" carries more emphasis on 'no' than "It's not a big deal for me."  Both are equally acceptable, and the difference is very subtle (in fact, some people may disagree with me on that difference in the first place).

Comment: thanks, the second question is in regard to *no** vs **not**

Comment: Ok, I revised my answer now that I understand your second question better.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use "not" or "no", but if you use "no", you need to omit the article, "a".

It's not a big deal.
It's no big deal.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it only addresses the last part of the question. The first part asked which preposition would be appropriate to use before **me** (*to* or *for*). Also, your answer could be improved with some sort of authoritative corroboration.

Answer (score 0):

All the variations you list are correct. Stylistically, I would go with either:

> It's not a big deal to me.

or

> It's no big deal for me.

The meaning is just barely different between these: the "for me" construction carries more of a 'volunteering for a task' implication than the "to me" version. So "The choice of stuffing for this year's turkey is really not a big deal to me", but "Cooking Thanksgiving dinner is no big deal for me."

Answer (score -1):

"To me" to me (lol) seems to express opinion, whereas, "for me" is talking more about how something affects you.

Examples:
*To me, it's too hot in here.*  (In my opinion, it needs to be cooler in here.  A cooler temperature would better suite this place/situation.)
*It's too hot for me.*  (It's hotter than what I can handle.)